# How to apply Bootstrap4 form related classes to fields in Django (v3) UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I'm building a a sign up form. The form is defined as follows:

```py
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Username'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, help_text='Required',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'email'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name','email', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {
            'password1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

This is what signup.html looks like:

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}"> {{ field.label_tag }} </label> 
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}


      </div>
    {% endfor %}



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>


</form>
```

With the above setup, the attributes passed to password1 and password2 fields do not get applied when the form is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One alternative to what you are trying to do is write your html code for password in separate html page and then apply class in the password**

**Like this: -**

> I hope this will help

```
password <input type="passsword" class='form-controle'>
```